# How to sort files and then populate a ListBox?

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

This code populate a ListBox with the file names of a specific folder

```
Dim DIRECTORY As String
DIRECTORY = Dir(myPath & "\*.xlsx", vbNormal)
Do Until DIRECTORY = ""
ListBox1.AddItem DIRECTORY
DIRECTORY = Dir()
Loop
```

But I want a sorted list.
How can I sort the files firstly and then populate the ListBox.
btw sorting a listbox is (as I know) a long procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `ListBox` does not have a built in sort capability.  You will need to roll your own.

The basic idea is to get the list data into an array, sort the array, and then put the data back in to the list.  There are many good references avaliable for sorting VBA arrays.

Unless you have a very large number of files, a simple sort will probably suffice.  Try This

```
Sub SortListBox(oLb As MSForms.ListBox)

Dim vItems As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim vTemp As Variant

'Put the items in a variant array
vItems = oLb.List

' Sort
For i = 0 To UBound(vItems, 1) - 1
    For j = i + 1 To UBound(vItems, 1)
        If vItems(i, 0) > vItems(j, 0) Then
            vTemp = vItems(i, 0)
            vItems(i, 0) = vItems(j, 0)
            vItems(j, 0) = vTemp
        End If
    Next
Next

'Clear the listbox
oLb.Clear

'Add the sorted array back to the listbox
For i = 0 To UBound(vItems, 1)
    oLb.AddItem vItems(i, 0)
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The DIR command always displays elements sorted alphabetically but by name, not type.
The correct thing would be to take advantage of the "vbDirectory" and "vbArchive" attributes and first create a list with vbDirectory and then another with vbArchive. The result is a single alphabetically sorted list that separates directories from files.

[image]

```
Private Sub ListarFunc()
Dim a As Integer
Dim strArchivo As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim TipoArchivo As String
Dim fso As Object, file As Object, folder As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

On Error Resume Next
    
    'If we are not in /root add a "\" to the PathExplorer
    If Mid(Me.BoxPathExplorer, 4, 1) <> "" Then Me.BoxPathExplorer = CurDir() & "\"
    Me.Lista1.ForeColor = RGB(25, 25, 100)
    Me.Lista1.RowSource = ""    'First, clear the list
    Me.Lista1.AddItem "___________________ TIPO ___________________" & ";" & "________________ " & _
        Dir(Me.BoxPathExplorer, vbVolume) & " ________________"
            
    strArchivo = Dir(Me.BoxPathExplorer, vbDirectory)
    While strArchivo <> ""
        Set folder = fso.GetFolder(strArchivo)
        If folder.Attributes And vbDirectory Then Me.Lista1.AddItem folder.Type & ";" & strArchivo
        strArchivo = Dir
        Set folder = Nothing
    Wend

    strArchivo = Dir(Me.BoxPathExplorer, vbArchive)
    While strArchivo <> ""
        Set file = fso.GetFile(strArchivo)
        If file.Attributes And vbArchive Then Me.Lista1.AddItem file.Type & ";" & strArchivo
        strArchivo = Dir
        Set file = Nothing
    Wend
    
    If Lista1.ItemData(1) = "." Then Me.Lista1.RemoveItem 1            'Delete the item '.'
    Me.Lista1 = "NoSelection"
End Sub
```

Regards.